# Jinja Scope on Inherited Template

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am developing a website using Flask on the back-end and Jinja for templating. Every page should have the same image as part of the [Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/), except for one of them, where I want to customize the url with something peculiar to that page.

The child template (like all other templates) extends base, but only this one will ever have a value set for the variable *ob_image_url*, therefore I need to check if that value exists and if not set a default value.

When the child page.html template is rendered, I am always getting the default value and not the one for that page. Where am I messing it up?

Thanks!

**base.html**

```
{% block og_image %}{% endblock %}
{% if not og_image_url %}
{% set og_image_url = url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png', _external=True) %}
{% endif %}
<meta property="og:image" content="{{og_image_url}}" />
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block og_image %}
    {% if obj and obj.image %}
        {% set og_image_url = obj.image %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work when blocks are used. Just remove the block part and see if it works.

Comment: That's it. It works now. Thanks!!